# Laravel where in a relational database

Tags: laravel

I have two tables
Thread and Participants
Thread has many participants and I'm able to access it like so:

```
Thread::with('participants')->get();
```

The `participants` table has a column `last_read`
I would like to get all participants from thread `WHERE last_read is NULL`.  I've tried this but it returns an error.

```
Thread::with('participants')
                          ->where('last_read', NULL)
                          ->get();
```

I am getting this error:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'last_read' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `threads` where `last_read` is null and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null)

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Also, share your error.

Comment: Use `whereNull()`, as you can see in the [official documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

Comment: whereNull() same error @LucasArbex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a query on relation table use whereHas

```
Thread::with('participants')
    ->whereHas('participants', function($q){
         $q->where('last_read', NULL);
    })->get();
```